# A valid environment variable to satisfy env:PRISMA_SECRET could not be found

Tags: sql, reactjs, orm, graphql, prisma

When I try to generate a Prisma token, it keeps giving me the following error, even though I have the `PRISMA_SECRET` configured in `config/dev.env.`:

```
A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration!    
'env:PRISMA_SECRET' could not be found.
```

My `config/dev.env` is configured as following:

```
PRISMA_ENDPOINT=http://local:4466/
PRISMA_SECRET=somesecret
JWT_SECRET=somesecret
```

And following is how I start `npm run dev`:

`"dev": "env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js --ext js,graphql --exec babel-node",`

When I `console.log(process.env.PRISMA_SECRET`), it shows the variable properly so I'm not sure what's going on. I'm tried restarting Docker and re-deploying Prisma, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an -f flag, it's to do with an update to env-cmd

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js  --exec babel-node -e js,graphql",
```